# Programmatically navigate to server page if route is not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have code navigating to some url after timeout:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() { self.context.history.pushState(null, '/somePage'); }, 5000);
},
```

But I want this page to be loaded from server, not as component in SPA code.
So when I do that, I just have:

```
Warning: Location "/somePage" did not match any routes
```

And nothing happens. 
How to do it in correct way?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use:

```
window.location = "/somePage";
```

So:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() { window.location="/somePage"; }, 5000);
},
```

Comment: kinda defeats the purpose of the router

Comment: It definitely works, thank you, but the point is to look up the url on the server if the route is not found. This way it goes straight to server...